# C++ const safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In C++11, I create threads with `std::thread`. And I have some global variables:

```
const int max_size = 78;
const int cat[5] = {1, 20, 3, 40, 5};
```

Now, if my threads read those variables, is there any chance of unidentified behavior?

Comment: You should be fine in this case, although you probably meant ["undefined" or "unspecified"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984) behavior.

Comment: I am not writing to const variables.

Comment: C++ defines a data race as simultaneous access to the same memory location by two or more threads, at least one of which is a modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as those variables are never written to (yes it is possible to write to `const` variables in C++ via pointer manipulation, but for what reason?) then no.

If you are worried about undefined or unspecified behavior (with respect to thread safety), you could always use a mutex.

An OK example:

```
// Globals
const int max_size = 78;
const int cat[5] = {1, 20, 3, 40, 5};

void call_from_thread() {
    std::cout << "Max Size: " << max_size << std::endl;
    std::cout << "cat[0]: " << cat[0] << std::endl;
    //..
    std::cout << "cat[4]: " << cat[4] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    //Launch some threads
    std::thread thread1(call_from_thread);
    std::thread thread2(call_from_thread);

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    //..

    *((int*)&cat[3])=15; // Since threads are joined, this is OK as far as the write is concerned
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, writing to a `const` variable can cause undefined behavior. So it is still a REALLY BAD idea.

A really really bad example:

```
int main() {
    //Launch some threads
    std::thread thread1(call_from_thread);
    std::thread thread2(call_from_thread);

    *((int*)&cat[3])=15; // BAD idea for thread safety as well as what is discussed above.

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    //..

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I remove the const, edit the variables on the main and start threads that only read the variables, I am still OK?

Comment: As long as the "start" threads are launched from the main thread and no subsequent writes happen after they are launched then yes you are OK.

Comment: If I remove the const from cat array and start 5 threads passing to each cat[i], do I need mutex? Those threads will write to cat[i]. Also, mutex gives a performance hit, right?

Comment: @Luka As long as those threads **do not write** to the *location* of `cat[i]`, you're fine. If you're passing `cat[i]` by value, that's also fine.

Comment: If I start 5 threads and I want them to return a value each, is this possible without mutex?

Comment: As long as they are **just returning (reading) the value and not writing**, then no you do not need a mutex. If you are writing, then you absolutely need a mutex.

Comment: The C++ memory model is extremely generous with instruction reordering and stramge architctures: are you folks certain?

Comment: `// This is OK` - no it isn't, modifying objects declared to be `const` has undefined behavior. It's not a data race, but it's far from "OK."

Comment: @Casey: I suppose I wasn't specific enough with `// (but not good programming)`. I meant in terms of the write.

Comment: @ChrisDargis Correct, you are not specific enough. "But not good programming" is not a clear indication of undefined behavior, especially when preceded by "This is OK."

Comment: It's not sufficient to say "this is not good programming". It is _worse_ than a data race. You shall simply not do it.

Comment: If you inject even trace amounts of stupid into a program, it will be come ill.